# How to assign an array of string to char**

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to load in several strings from files and put them into an array of strings. This is how I am trying to do that

```
char** source_str;
size_t* source_size;

void load_source()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("simple_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *source_kernel = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    fclose( fp );


    fp = fopen("advect.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *advect_source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);

    source_str = {source_kernel, advect_source_str};        
    fclose( fp );
}
```

However, this is the error I am getting: "Excess elements in scalar initializer"
How do I assign an array of strings (or more accurately pointer to pointers to chars) to `char** source_str;` ?

Comment: This is C, not C++ code

Comment: In C++ you'd probably make a vector of strings, like this: `std::vector<std::string> >`

Comment: @MrEricSir writing in C++, it just might be that this piece of code looks a lot like C code. The reason is because I am using the OpenCL library, and it takes a char** as one of its arguments for an array of strings.

Comment: Your error,`"excess elements in scalar initializer"`, is coming from this line: `source_str = {source_kernel, advect_source_str};`.  C or C++, that line is bogus.

Comment: @IlyaLapan -- C++ code would use `std::fstream` rather than `FILE*` and its buddies, and `new` instead of `malloc`.